# Two issues with lualatex: italics and hyphenation

Tags: luatex

I found two problems with lualatex, that does not appear when using just latex:

1. Text within `{\em ...}` is not shown in italics (it is shown correctly if I compile with latex instead of lualatex).
2. Hyphenation rules with `\hyphenation{...}` does not seem to work and some text exceeds the margin (this problem does not occur with latex).

Here is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[preprint, 11pt, times, letterpaper, authoryear, review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\newcommand*{\useLuatex}{} % comment this line to compile with latex instead of luatex.
\ifdefined\useLuatex
\usepackage{xcolor,luacolor,lua-ul}
\LuaULSetHighLightColor{yellow}
\fi

\hyphenation{ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-long-word-that-needs-hy-phens}

%Uncommment the following two lines to solve the problem with italics.
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman} % Replace with a font that has an italic variant

\begin{document}

First, the following word is in italics: {\em italics}.

This is an example with a veryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryverylongwordthatneedshyphens.

\end{document}
```

In the example, the very long word gets out of margin and the word "italics" is not shown in italics. I was able to solve the problem with the italics by including these two lines:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman} % Replace with a font that has an italic variant
```

However, I don't know if this is the right way to go. I would like to keep the same default font that is used when I compile with latex and I don't have those two lines included.

The obvious solution would be to use latex instead of lualatex. However, I need to use lualatex in order to use reliable highlights with package lua-ul. Any ideas about how this could be solved?

Comment: as always on this site, please provide a full minimal exmaple tht others can copy and test. That we we have a better understanding of what exactly you are doing and what your setup is.

Comment: Simply put, neither problem you describe should be happening. Unfortunately, while you've described a couple of problems, you've not given any information as to what's going on in your document. Please do tell us which TeX distribution you employ and when it was last updated. How do you load fonts -- by loading the `fontspec` package and issuing suitable `\setmainfont` and `\setsansfont` instructions? Which font do you use, and have you activated the font's italic font face properly? Which language is your document written in, and how do you activate language-specific hyphenation rules?

Comment: Sorry for not providing a minimal working example. I have included it now in the original question. I hope it helps to clarify the issue.

Comment: we can not compare your example in lualatex and pdflatex as you provided a document that only runs with lualatex

Comment: latex does warn that italics are not set up with the fonts you are using: `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape \`TU/txr/m/it' undefined
(Font)              using \`TU/txr/m/n' instead on input line 15.` (hyphenation does work though)

Comment: I have modified the MWE so that it can also be compiled with latex. For that, one can simply comment the line "\newcommand*{\useLuatex}{}". That said, in my specific example the "veryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryverylongwordthatneedshyphens" word does not seem to break independently of whether I use lualatex or latex. It is not realistic because the word does not exist (it is just for the MWE), but I'm quite confused about this. Any idea is welcome.

Comment: There's a basic, and highly detrimental, issue with your document setup: You specify `times` as one of the document class options. If you examine carefully what the pursuit of this option implies, you'll learn that it means that the font setup is done and over with long before the `fontspec` package gets loaded and that the hyphenation of superlong words is not enabled. Remove the `times` option to see the practical importance of this issue.

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed, if I remove the "times" option of the \documentclass then the hypenation works when I compile with Latex; however, it does not work if I compile with lualatex; any idea about why this may be happening would be great. On the other hand, the "times" option was in the template I was given, so I'm not sure if I am allowed to remove the option.

Answer (score 1):

The `times` option to the `elsarticle` class loads the largely deprecated `txfonts` package. Avoid it.

Load `newtx` instead, that supports OpenType Times text fonts.

In the example I show that all hyphenation points are found.

```
\documentclass[
  preprint,
  11pt,
  letterpaper,
  authoryear,
  review
]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{iftex}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\ifluatex
\usepackage{xcolor,luacolor,lua-ul}
\LuaULSetHighLightColor{yellow}
\fi

\hyphenation{ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-ve-ry-long-word-that-needs-hy-phens}

\begin{document}

First, the following word is in italics: \textit{italics}.
Then, the following word is emphasized: \emph{emphasis}.

This is an example with a veryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryverylongwordthatneedshyphens.

\parbox[t]{0pt}{\linespread{1}\tiny
  This is an example with a veryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryveryverylongwordthatneedshyphens.}

\end{document}
```

By the way, `{\em ...}` is *not* the way to get italics. If you want emphasis, use `\emph{...}`, if you definitely want italics, use `\textit{...}`. They *may* render the same, but are semantically different.

[image]

You may want to load some packages for “non LuaLaTeX”, but if your document relies on `lua-ul`, just load the packages unconditionally.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. However, I tried to compile this example with lualatex and the hyphenation does not work (it works if I compile it with latex). Maybe there is a strange problem with my latex installation?

Comment: @user173026 your initial example should have hyphenated with lualatex, you seem to have the patterns misconfigured